# Pass an object with JS throw new Error in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, express

I want to throw an error in my node application as follows.

```
throw new Error({ status: 400, error: 'Email already exists' });
```

this give me the following output.

```
Error: [object Object]
```

I can't access the properties of this error object. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That's not how you should handle http errors in nodeJs. The error message should only conatin the message associated not the status! http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The constructor for an `Error` object expects a string, not an object (which is why your scheme doesn't work).

You are free to add your own custom properties to the Error object after you create it.

```
let err = new Error('Email already exists');
err.status = 400;
err.whateverElse = someValue;
throw err;
```

The standard properties on an error object are (for some reason I don't know) not enumerable so they don't show up in some contexts (even though they are there). Any new properties you add with plain assignment like above, will be enumerable.

FYI, you do this in multiple places, you can also subclass the `Error` object and give your subclass a constructor that takes whatever arguments you want to give it.  That constructor can then call `super(msg)` and then add its own properties to the error object from the constructor arguments.

The `[object Object]` is your message is because you are attempting to convert your error object to a string and the default string representation of the object is `[object Object]`.  That will happen if you trying to use your error object in a string such as:

```
console.log('Error: ' + err);
```

Instead, you should pass the whole object to `console.log()` like this:

```
console.log('Error:', err);
```

And, the `console.log()` gets the whole object and can display its properties.

---

You can also make your own error subclass that then takes whatever constructor arguments you want.  So, if you want to pass an object to your custom error object, you can do that like this:

```
class MyError extends Error {
    constructor(data) {
       super(data.message);
       this.status = data.status;
    }
}

throw new MyError({ status: 400, message: 'Email already exists' });
```

Comment: I'm trying to access error.status but its undefined. How would i access it? @jfriend00

Comment: @O'DaneBrissett - You would have to show your actual code for us to know where things have gone wrong.  Please write your own question and show your specific implementation of this.

Comment: Note: this will not work with TypeScript (at least as intended). One needs to extend the class

Comment: Fantastic! so much easier than trying to create a custom error type

Comment: Added custom MyError class as an option.

Answer (score 5):

you could try with [the `cause` propoty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) of :

> TS has inaccurate value type about it at present, [this is being discussed on the official to revolve it](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48098).

```
try {
     throw new Error('Email already exists', { 
       cause: { status: 400 } 
     });
   } catch(e) {
     console.log(e); // Error('Email already exists')
     console.log(e.cause) // { status: 400 }
   }
```

or throw the Error instance with the custom property

```
try {
     const error = new Error('Email already exists');
     error.status = 400;
     throw error;
   } catch(e) {
     console.log(e); // Error('Email already exists')
     console.log(e.status) // 400
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

The Error object takes a string parameter as the first parameter.

JSON.stringify the object if you are looking to print it out to the console.

```
throw new Error(JSON.stringify({ status: 400, error: 'Email already exists' }));
```

You will get something like this:
Uncaught Error: {"status":400,"error":"Email already exists"}

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: This would require the user of this error object to then parse the JSON.  There's no reason to stringify it (see my answer for how else to do it).

Comment: I have no clue why this has so many upvotes. It literally does not make sense to stringify the json to a string: There's almost no cases where you'd want to echo out json than simply just writing out something like `Error status: ${status}, Returned: ${error}`...he likely wants to reuse these errors later on, which the other answer would be a much better answer.

Comment: Even though I have used `Error` as a base class for my use case, the answer might be relevant if you do not want to extend it but want to send some raw data to the client for further processing such as localisation purposes.